# Is it possible to check for minus 0 in cpp?

Tags: c++

This might be a silly question, but I really have an issue here with 0 and minus 0.

I am calculating a slope of a function and depending on the vector ( right or left ) it is 0 or -0.

Is it possible to do a if condition and find out if the slope is 0 or -0 ?  Doing the below doesnt work.

```
if ( slope == 0.0f )
std::cout << "direction vector towards right";
else if ( slope == -0.0f )
std::cout << "direction vector towards left"
```

I deliberatly didnt put working source code, because I think it is irrelevant for the question. A simple answer for the above will help.

Comment: thank you.. I should have searched for "negative" 0 instead of "minus" 0 !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit). Both zeroes are equal to each other so your check doesn't work, but the signbit is different.

Comment: thanks, need to wait for a couple of minutes ;)